# How do I make the minimize, close and maximize window buttons visible?

Tags: gnome, pop-os, nemo

I am pretty much a linux noob, and I just recently started using Pop OS version 22.04 with GNOME version 42.4 

Desktop icons weren't showing correctly on Nautilus so I've installed Nemo. Used `xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search` to make Nemo default, but I still kept Nautilus installed. 

The issue that I'm encountering is that the Close, Minimize and Maximize buttons in the titlebar are not showing at all. I have enabled those options in the PopOS settings and in Tweaks, and all the applications have those. It seems to be isolated to Nemo. 
On a previous install of Pop running the same versions, Nemo had those buttons and worked fine. 

Fixes I've tried include: 
`sudo apt reinstall nemo`
`sudo apt purge nemo nemo*` followed by reinstall 
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/nemo3` 
and trying to manually modify the Schema file for `nemo-desktop`